# Reason for starting with capital letter

Tags: capitalization

> "DURSLEY!" he boomed.
>   Uncle Vernon, who had gone very pale, whispered something that sounded like "**Mimblewimble**." Hagrid stared wildly at Harry.
>    "But yeh must know about yer mom and dad," he said. "I mean, they're famous. You're famous." 
>   "What? My -- my mom and dad weren't famous, were they?"
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

What’s the reason that “Mimblewimble” starts with a capital letter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it seems that capitalization was a rather arbitrary decision.

It could be argued that it is capitalized because it is the beginning of a "sentence", though really it is just a single word, and a made up, gibberish word at that. In this case, there really is no concrete rule about whether to capitalize or not. Since it's a made up word, it could be a proper or improper noun, a proper, full sentence quote (requiring a capital) or simply an excerpt (not requiring one), both at the discretion of the author.

Answer (score 2):

A sentence, even a quoted sentence, should begin with a capital letter. This is true even if the sentence is short and/or not grammatically correct.

For example:

> He whispered something that sounded like, "It is sunny out."

We are quoting a sentence, so it should be capitalized.

> He whispered something that sounded like, "Sunny out."

It's not a complete sentence, but we still capitalize.

We normally capitalize exclamations by the same reasoning:

> He shouted something that sounded like, "Hooray!"

But if we are quoting an excerpt from a single sentence, then we don't normally capitalize.

> He insisted we leave "in the morning".

This case is ambiguous because it's a nonsense word, so we don't know if it's supposed to be a complete sentence, an exclamation, or just a fragment. I would have capitalized it also, as it seems like the implication is that it's quoting the entirely of what he said, which would presumably be construed as a full sentence. But it's debatable.

Answer (score 1):

Quotations should start with capital letters since those are sentences themselves.

For example if we say the following :: 
This has definitely been my best birthday yet.

We start with a capital letter using the normal sentence grammar rules. Now when we put this into a quote. It becomes::

He whispered to his mother, "This has definitely been my best birthday yet."

It stays the same. All sentences must start with a capital letter. The only reason to not start with a capital is if you are talking about something whose proper/common name starts without a capital letter.

For example ::

iPhone usage in Canada has now surpassed Android in statistics. 
This would remain the same in a quote, example : 
He said with authority, "iPhone usage in Canada…"

In the case above, since the person is mumbling, we're not sure what he said. Therefore we assume a capitalization of the sentence. If we knew that he was talking about say iMax 3D, there could have been a non-capitalized sentence.